# How to use varargs to print out strings?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

How can I use varargs to print out multiple strings? I tried this but I cannot determine the size of the array. It just prints garbage.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$POINTERMATH ON}

function _Print(const S: String): string; cdecl;
var
  Args: Array[0..100] of Pointer absolute S;
  I: Integer;
begin
  I := 0;
  while Args[I] <> nil do
  begin
    WriteLn(PString(@Args[I])^);
    Inc(I);
  end;
end;

const Print: function(const S: String): string; cdecl varargs = _Print;

var
  A, B: String;
begin
  A := 'ABC';
  B := 'CDE';
  Print(a, b, 'asdasd', 'fasd', ' ')
end.
```

Comment: Why do you need to do all this? Delphi supports arrays, and has functions that allow you to obtain the `Length`, `Low` index, and `High` index values into the array. You can simply pass the array to your function and iterate through it without trying to jump through all these hoops. Your function declaration then becomes `procedure Print(Values: array of string);`.

Comment: It's not *faster*. Where did you get that ridiculous idea? *I prefer pointers* is nonsense. For what you're attempting to do here, there's no speed improvement, and it's an unnecessary level of complexity. (I'm leaving this comment even though you deleted your comment that it responds to immediately after I posted this reply. For the benefit of others, it said *Because its faster. I prefer ponters*.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `varargs` function has no automated way to determine the number of arguments being passed, because only the caller knows how many parameters it is putting on the call stack.  The function must determine the arguments manually, either by:

1. requiring the caller to pass the actual number of parameter as a fixed parameter:

   ```
   function _Print(NumStrings: Integer; const Strings: string): string; cdecl;
   var
     Args: Array[0..100] of Pointer absolute Strings;
     I: Integer;
   begin
     for I := 0 to NumStrings-1 do
     begin
       WriteLn(PString(@Strings[I])^);
     end;
   end;

   const
     Print: function(NumStrings: Integer; const Strings: string): string; cdecl varargs = _Print;

   var
     A, B: String;
   begin
     A := 'ABC';
     B := 'CDE';
     Print(5, a, b, 'asdasd', 'fasd', ' ');
   end.
   ```
2. putting a sentry value at the end of the parameter list that the function can then look for.  Your function is already coded for this (it is looking for a `nil` pointer), so just pass one:

   ```
   Print(a, b, 'asdasd', 'fasd', ' ', nil);
   ```

That being said, either approach is subject to caller error and thus potentially dangerous if misused, which is why `varargs`-style functions are not used very often.  You should consider using an **open-array** parameter instead:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$POINTERMATH ON}

function _Print(const Args: array of string): string;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := Low(Args) to High(Args) do
  begin
    WriteLn(Args[I]);
  end;
end;

const
  Print: function(const Args: array of string): string = _Print;

var
  A, B: String;
begin
  A := 'ABC';
  B := 'CDE';
  Print([a, b, 'asdasd', 'fasd', ' ']);
end.
```

Comment: That's not quite true. It is used in RTL. `UStrCatN`

Comment: @user15124: I did not say they were not used at all. I said they are not used very often.  Not even in the RTL.  Besides, if you actually look at the implementation of `UStrCatN` more carefully, you will see it has an `ArgCnt` fixed parameter. The compiler fills in that value, as it knows how many strings it is concatenating together.

Comment: @user15124: In the RTL, especially in System.pas, there are functions that have quite a bit of compiler magic behind them. IIRC, some even have different parameters than EAX,EDX,ECX, so the System unit can hardly be seen as prime example of pure Delphi. Fact is that Delphi does not (without tricks) allow you to write varargs functions. Use array of const instead.

Comment: Agreed. `varags` exists in Delphi only for *consuming* variadic C functions, like `printf()` and `wsprintf()`. It is not meant for *writing* such functions. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions#External_Declarations) even says so: "*The varargs directive **works only with external routines** and only with the cdecl calling convention.*"